# Navbar being covered by an overlay in Bootstrap [only in safari]

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, overlay, navbar

As seen here:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/HpoIc.jpg
I created a navbar using Bootstrap and created a color overlay to the div below, but the navbar is now being covered by the overlay. This only happens in safari. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="jumbotron textLeft wow fadeInLeft" id="introductionMain">
   <div class="overlay" style="height:100vh;">
      <div class="container verticalCenter" id="introductionmainContent">
        <h1>Unleash your <b>Creativity.</b></h1>
        <p>Creativity Through Arts aims to encourage <b><span class="liveType"></span>
        </b> to pursue their artistic paths.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#performerMain" role="button">For Performers</a>
        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="/events" role="button">For Volunteers</a>
       </p>
       <div>
     </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
.overlay {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
/*background-color: rgba(255,165,0,0.7);*/
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
background:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* FF3.6+ */
background:     -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* IE10 */
background:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* W3C */


position: relative;
z-index:9999;
color:white;}
```

Comment: please post you HTML and any custom CSS, otherwise we would just be guessing...

Comment: Assuming you have your `<div class="navbar"></div>` first then your `<div class="jumbotron textLeft wow fadeInLeft" id="introductionMain">`, then its going to overlap because of your css, Notice how you put position: absolute and top: 0; Also you have a weird height syntax error: `<div class="overlay" style="height:100vh;">`

Comment: How would I go about resolving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the styling properties from the ".overlay" class except for background and color.

```
.overlay {
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9),     rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* Chrome 10+, Saf5.1+ */
  background:    -moz-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9),     rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* FF3.6+ */
  background:     -ms-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* IE10 */
  background:      -o-linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* Opera 11.10+ */
  background:         linear-gradient(45deg, rgba(255,78,80,0.9), rgba(249,212,35,0.9)); /* W3C */
  color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) Add `position:relative` to your `#introductionMain` div

2) Remove `position:relative` from your `.overlay` div

Comment: This makes the content below underneath the overlay, rather than the picture.
http://imgur.com/AfsUkqB

Comment: Ok I understand. As soon as you make #introductionMain positioned absolutely, it loses its ability to take up the space made by its contents. What if you removed all the styling properties from the ".overlay" class except for background and color?

Comment: Great @Paul  I will add it as an answer so you can accept it.